# Failed to start Apache after configuring ssl on Amazon Linux2

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, apache2

I'm trying to install ssl certificate on aws ec2(Amazon Linux2). Apache can start properly until I configure ssl following "Step 1: Enable TLS on the server" in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-ami.html

After I make those changes, apache even can not start:

```
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code
```

I got the following log by typing "journalctl -xe":

```
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit session-26.scope has begun starting up.
Jan 27 04:30:01 ip-172-31-18-58.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal CROND[10239]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jan 27 04:30:01 ip-172-31-18-58.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of root.
-- Subject: Unit user-0.slice has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit user-0.slice has finished shutting down.
Jan 27 04:30:01 ip-172-31-18-58.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopping User Slice of root.
-- Subject: Unit user-0.slice has begun shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit user-0.slice has begun shutting down.
Jan 27 04:30:47 ip-172-31-18-58.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal sshd[10245]: Received disconnect from 221.181.185.135 port 21146:11:  [preauth]
Jan 27 04:30:47 ip-172-31-18-58.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal sshd[10245]: Disconnected from 221.181.185.135 port 21146 [preauth]
Jan 27 04:31:22 ip-172-31-18-58.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal dhclient[2893]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 120170ms.
Jan 27 04:33:22 ip-172-31-18-58.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal dhclient[2893]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 119290ms.
Jan 27 04:34:55 ip-172-31-18-58.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal sshd[10251]: Received disconnect from 218.93.208.150 port 29589:11:  [preauth]
Jan 27 04:34:55 ip-172-31-18-58.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal sshd[10251]: Disconnected from 218.93.208.150 port 29589 [preauth]
Jan 27 04:35:17 ip-172-31-18-58.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal sudo[10253]: ec2-user : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/etc/pki/tls/certs ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemct
Jan 27 04:35:17 ip-172-31-18-58.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal sudo[10253]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by ec2-user(uid=0)
Jan 27 04:35:17 ip-172-31-18-58.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit httpd.service has begun starting up.
Jan 27 04:35:17 ip-172-31-18-58.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 27 04:35:17 ip-172-31-18-58.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit httpd.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Jan 27 04:35:17 ip-172-31-18-58.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jan 27 04:35:17 ip-172-31-18-58.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Jan 27 04:35:17 ip-172-31-18-58.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal sudo[10253]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan 27 04:35:22 ip-172-31-18-58.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal dhclient[2893]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 130780ms.
```

I get stuck here for a long time. Anyone can help me please? Thank you in advance.